# JS Firebase: Service worker unable to nagivate

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am working on a website that uses `firebase messaging` and for this a custom service worker for `firebase` is registered to the website.

The website is somewhat a webchat that synchronizes and stores the messages in `firebase database` and the website uses `angular-ui-router` for getting the messages key from the url, the website shows a notification when a new message is received from the client and the url is modified for the related message if the notification was clicked, however this has been a struggle for the service worker side when the website is not on focus because the service worker throws an error saying `unable to navigate`

the service worker code is this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    "messagingSenderId": "######"
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
    var title = payload.data.title;
    var options = {
        body: payload.data.message,
        icon: "apple-touch-icon.png",
        data: {
            postId: payload.data.postKey
        }
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(evt){
    var postKey   = evt.notification.data.postId;
    var origin    = evt.target.origin;
    var urlTarget = origin + "/#!/" + postKey;

    evt.notification.close();

    evt.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll({
            includeUncontrolled: true,
            type: "window"
        })
        .then(function(clientList) {  
            if(clientList.length > 0){
                var client = clientList[0];

                client.navigate(urlTarget);

                if(client.focus){
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }

            if(self.clients.windowOpen){
                return self.clients.windowOpen(urlTarget);
            }
        }));
});
```

the behavior i am expecting is as follow:

**on focus:**

- Message received
- Show notification
- Modify url address when notification clicked

before notification click: `https://example.com/#!/`

after notification click: `https://example.com/#!/-key`

**on non-focus:**

- Push received
- Modify data for displaying notification
- Show notification
- Focus/Open website on notification click
- Modify url address when focus/open

When focus/open: `https://example.com/#!/-key`

The code that shows the notification on focus works fine so i don't think that posting the code is necessary.

any help on this is appreciated, i have spent literally all the alternative options i have thought on this

Comment: did you try: return clients.windowOpen(urlTarget); 
instead of return self.clients.windowOpen(urlTarget); I use it this way in my application and it works. Also in the following link it is described without the self keyword: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

As [per the specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#client-navigate) (see 4.2.10, step 4), one of the reasons why `WindowClient.navigate()` might reject is if the active service worker for the client is not the same as the current service worker that's executing the code. In other words, if the window isn't controlled by the current service worker, that service worker can't tell it to navigate to a given URL.

I'd recommend that you use

```
self.clients.matchAll({
  includeUncontrolled: false,
  type: 'window'
})
```

to ensure that you only get back `WindowClient` instances that *are* controlled by the current service worker.

Comment: Could you pass along the exact error that's being logged along with the code at the specific line number associated with the error?